# Join Table A or Table B in a single query based on some condition

Tags: sql, oracle11g

A table has trades info.

[image]

The values for grd_market_exchange_cd are mapped to different time_zone_name, which can be obtained by the following ways:

```
WITH time_zone AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
            grd.grd_market_exchange_cd,
            ex.time_zone_name
        FROM mdm_code.exchange_grd_exchange_map mp
        JOIN mdm_code.grd_market_exchange grd ON grd.grd_market_exchange_cd = mp.grd_market_exchange_cd
        JOIN mdm.market_exchange ex ON ex.market_exchange_cd = mp.market_exchange_cd
        WHERE ex.deactivation_dt IS NULL
        AND EXISTS (
            SELECT 'X'
            FROM ae_os_market_exchange e
            WHERE e.market_exchange_cd = ex.market_exchange_cd
            AND e.jobs_load_id = ( SELECT MAX(jobs_load_id) FROM ae_os_market_exchange )
        )
        AND ex.time_zone_name IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT
    at.trade_id,
    at.trade_execution_tmstmp,
    at.grd_market_exchange_cd,
    tz.time_zone_name
FROM cd_data.allocated_trade at
JOIN time_zone tz ON tz.grd_market_exchange_cd = at.grd_market_exchange_cd
WHERE TRUNC(TRADE_EXECUTION_TMSTMP) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)
AND TRADE_STATUS_CD IN ('EX','TR')
AND trade_id IN (
308983463,
308983465,
308983929,
308983950,
308979467
);
```

[image]

Option 1:
This is the first way. But the problem in fetching time_zone_name in this way is:

- grd_market_exchange_cd is NULL in some cases.
- 1 grd_market_exchange_cd is mapped to 2 or more time zones in some cases.
- grd_market_exchange_cd to time_zone_name mapping is not their for some codes.

We have pick time_zone_name through this way every time, except these three cases mentioned above. As seen above, I get two rows for the same trades if grd_market_exchange_cd
is mapped to 2 time zones or no row if it is NULL or not mapped.

Option 2:
If somehow I don't get time_zone_name by using grd_market_exchange_cd, then I would have to use different tables to fetch the value, as shown below:

```
SELECT
    at.trade_id,
    at.trade_execution_tmstmp,
    at.grd_market_exchange_cd,
    mme.time_zone_name
FROM cd_data.allocated_trade at
JOIN ae_os_listing_v l ON at.tradable_ent_id = l.cde_tradable_entity_id
JOIN ae_os_market_exchange me ON me.listing_key_id = l.listing_key_id
JOIN mdm.market_exchange mme ON me.market_exchange_cd = mme.market_exchange_cd
WHERE TRUNC(trade_execution_tmstmp) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)
AND at.trade_status_cd IN ('EX','TR')
AND me.jobs_load_id = (SELECT MAX(jobs_load_id) FROM ae_os_market_exchange)
AND me.global_exchange_designation_cd = 'P'
AND trade_id IN (
308983463,
308983465,
308983929,
308983950,
308979467
);
```

[image]

I have to develop a single query merging the above two queries so that I pick time_zone_name via Option 1, if grd_market_exchange_cd is mapped to exactly 1 time_zone_name or via Option 2, if I don't obtain a time_zone_name value via Option 1.

Comment: aaarrrgghh my eyes!!!! But anyway firstly how do you to propose to select one timezone if a particular code matches 2? The highest, lowest, first or average? We need to know this before we can pose a solution. With regards to the other question, To have 'two tries' at looking up a code you simply outer join to both tables and then 'coalesce' the result in the order that you want. But you can't do that until you solve your one-many issue somehow. You also might want to consider creating a new 'cleaned up' timezone table that makes this task easier.

Comment: If I get more than one or zero time_zone from the temp table at the starting of the 1st query, then I need to get the time_zone value using Option 2 tables which would give a single value.

Comment: @AlexPoole - Hi Alex. Can you please help me here.

Comment: What I suggest you do is extend your initial `WITH time_zone` to only return records that have a single time zone (using `HAVING` or `ROW_NUMBER` to identify and exclude those with duplicates). Now outer join to that. Now outer join to your other optional timezone table. Now you can simply use `coalesce` to pick the first non null result from each table. I'm not going to rewrite your query for you at this stage. First at least try to rewrite your initial WITH to return results that are unique on `grd_market_exchange_cd` (by excluding duplicates using `HAVING` or `ROW_NUMBER`)

Comment: Sure @Nick.McDermaid I will draft a query with your suggestions and put it here. Thanks!!